# How can I hide other plugins icon from wordpress editor?

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

I want to make form for non login user with editor.
I chosed wordpress default editor/Tiny mce. I installed "advanced editor tools" for editor.
I also install "modula" gallery plugin.
I don't want my editor to show modula gallery plugin icon but it keeps reveal it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOBOx.png)
Is there any method I can remove the modula icon from editor?

How can I hide other plugins icon in wordpress editor?

When I uninstall modula then it disappear. When I use other image plugin then it disapears too.
I could remove all other icon in tiny editor by using "advanced edtitor tools" setting but there is no setting to remove modula icon.